# DEVp2p Wire Protocol tutorial on geth or Web3.js/Web3.py

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, web3.py, protocol, devp2p

I was looking to develop an application using `ÐΞVp2p Wire Protocol` and I'm having trouble finding an example or tutorial. I was able to find only `ÐΞVp2p Wire Protocol`'s [wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/%C3%90%CE%9EVp2p-Wire-Protocol).

**[Q]** Does anybody has a working example or tutorial such as sending `Hello World` message between a receiver and sender for `ÐΞVp2p Wire Protocol` that works with the recent version of `geth` or `Web3.js`/`Web3.py`?

Comment: It's not in any of the three places you requested, but `trinity`/`py-evm` has a working p2p implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I found all these articles from the same author very useful:

1. [Ethereum from scratch - Part 1: Ping](https://ocalog.com/post/10/)
2. [Ethereum from scratch - Part 2: Pinging a Bootnode](https://ocalog.com/post/18/)
3. [Ethereum from scratch - Part 3: Decoding Bootnode Response](https://ocalog.com/post/20/)

You've mentioned a wiki page from this page, but I'll leave it here as it has a comprehensive explanation of Ethereum's [ÐΞV Technologies.](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/%C3%90%CE%9EV-Technologies)

Comment: The links you shared uses `py-eth`. I want a solution using `geth` or `web3`. @Daveldito